# Предикативная единица и предикативный центр это одно и то же?

Tags: синтаксис, предикатив

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Предикативный центр, как я понимаю, - грамматическая основа. Предикативная единица - это предложение, обладающее предикативностью (например,одно из простых предложений внутри сложного = 1 предикативная единица), или также предикативный центр?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно: предикативный центр - грамматическая основа. Предикативная единица - это простое предложение как предикативный минимум.

Предикативная единица - это синтаксическая конструкция, имеющая значение предикативности, оформленное структурной схемой. Эта конструкция имеет несколько возможностей функционирования, среди которых есть основные, важнейшие и другие, которые можно назвать периферийными.

1. Предикативная единица прежде всего функционирует как **простое предложение**. Между этими двумя понятиями есть различие: ПЕ - это структура, которая представлена предикативным минимумом, а простое предложение - это функционирующее образование, характеризующееся возможностью распространения и осложнения и интонационной оформленностью в единое целое. Предикативная единица не имеет интонационных характеристик - только структурные. Каждое простое предложение оформляется той или иной интонационной конструкцией, выражающей определенный тип высказывания (повествовательное, побудительное, желательное, вопросительное).
2. Другое функционирование ПЕ - употребление в качестве **компонента сложного предложения** (**поли**предикативной единицы). Эти компоненты (В народе говорят, что это добрая примета) являются предикативными единицами, но не простыми предложениями, поскольку не имеют интонационной законченности. Только все полипредикативное образование в целом является предложением - сложным.

Эти две функции являются главными, поскольку простое и сложное предложения создаются только предикативными единицами. Другие функции предикативной единицы - это всего лишь ее возможности, которые она имеет наряду с другими синтаксическими компонентами (словосочетаниями, словами и др.).

Предикативная единица может представлять собою компонент, не являющийся членом предложения, представляющий собою некую надстройку над структурой предложения: это вставные и вводные предложения. Например: Ермолай шел смело и безостановочно (**так хорошо заметил он дорогу**), лишь изредка покрикивая (И.Тургенев); Этот человек, **надо вам заметить**, жил в наших местах недавно.

Предикативная единица может замещать любой компонент простого предложения (одна из регулярных реализаций). Например: Работы много. - Работы - только успевай поворачиваться.

Таким образом, простое предложение по структуре - предикативная единица, сложное предложение - полипредикативная единица.

Comment: Людмила, а при чем тут добрые приметы? У вас, наверное, лишний текст вкрался?

Comment: Серж, Вы о предложении " Эти компоненты (В народе говорят, что это добрая примета) являются предикативными единицами"? Нет, не лишний текст, это пример сложного предложения, где каждая ПЕ является компонентом полипредикативной единицы.

Comment: Да, речь шла об этом предложении. Спасибо, понятно.